# Template resolution - operator<< not found with boost-test

Tags: c++, templates, boost-test

The following code works fine:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE TestFoo
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T> &v)
{
    os << "[ ";
    for ( const T& elem : v )
        os << elem << ' ';
    return os << ']';
}

typedef boost::dynamic_bitset<> BS;
static const std::vector<BS> foo = { BS(std::string("101")) };

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_foo )
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( foo[0], foo[0] );
}
```

However, when I replace the test case with

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_foo )
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( foo, foo );
}
```

then `operator<<` is no longer found by the compiler:

```
/usr/include/boost/test/test_tools.hpp:326:14: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<> >’)
```

I would expect the compiler to instantiate the `operator<<` template defined above. Why is this not happening / how to fix?

Comment: Unrelated: It's best to not use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. It's a g++ internal header that's supposed to support pre-compiled headers. Since it's non-standard, it can disappear or change dramatically any time you update the tool chain and it flat out doesn't exist on anything but g++.

Comment: @user4581301 Fair point, I simplified the example & removed that distraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: see comment, this is UB - there doesn't appear to be a "good" solution to the problem.

wrap your `op<<` in a `namespace std {...}`

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

namespace std { // THIS LINE

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T, Rest...> &v)
{
    os << "[ ";
    for ( const T& elem : v )
        os << elem << ' ';
    os << ']';
    return os;
}
} // THIS LINE

typedef boost::dynamic_bitset<> BS;
static const std::vector<BS> foo = { BS(std::string("101")) };


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_foo )
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( foo, foo );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xoW-IJ

Otherwise it's not looking in the right namespace for your implementation.   Pretty sure this is ADL: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: This exhibits undefined behavior, per [\[namespace.std\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#1)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yep, you're right.. but is there any way to introduce this in an ADL-aware fashion?

Comment: That does work, though I'm still not clear why it didn't find it before. The operator was defined in the global namespace, which I thought was always searched?

Comment: "Name lookup rules make it impractical to declare operators in global or user-defined namespace that operate on types from the std namespace, e.g. a custom operator>> or operator+ for std::vector or for std::pair (unless the element types of the vector/pair are user-defined types, which would add their namespace to ADL). Such operators would not be looked up from template instantiations, such as the standard library algorithms. See dependent names for further details."